# Token Expiration after 1 Hour in Authentication using Retrofit 2 and Logging Interceptor

Tags: android

In my case, I have used retrofit 2 library for networking.
 1. Token is generated while logged in and it expires after  1 hour which is passed through header.
 2. I have implemented Interceptor for adding the header.
 3. Whenever 401 unauthorized comes after the expiration, I have called the method callRefreshToken() which provides the refresh token. But I need to do this in background.
Hope for the help: Here's my code below,

```
 public static RetroInterfaceAPI getClient() {

    if (retroInterfaceAPI == null) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(String message) {
                Log.d("Retrofit", message);
            }
        });

        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY); // sap request ko kun thau log garne. Body garo bhane sap aauxa

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addInterceptor(new HeaderAuthoriztionInterceptor())
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .build();


        Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okClient)
                .baseUrl(Constant.URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        retroInterfaceAPI = client.create(RetroInterfaceAPI.class);
    }

    return retroInterfaceAPI;
}



  private static class HeaderAuthoriztionInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        request = request.newBuilder().header("Authorization", "Bearer " + new PrefsManager(MasterApplication.getmInstance()).getAccessToken())
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}



public void callReFreshToken() {
    mUserListAdapter.clears();


    mProgressDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    Map<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("refresh_token",new PrefsManager(getContext()).getRefreshTokenFromLogin());
    hashMap.put("grant_type","refresh_token");

    RestClient.RetroInterfaceAPI mInterface = RestClient.getClient();
    Call<Login> call = mInterface.getRefreshToken(hashMap);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {


            if (response != null) {
                mProgressDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                new PrefsManager(getContext()).setAccessToken(response.body().getAccesstoken());



            }else {
                mProgressDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
            mProgressDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Authenticator for refresh token automatically when it's expired

**Your client should be**

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addInterceptor(new HeaderAuthoriztionInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .authenticator(new TokenAuthenticator()) 
            .builder.build()
```

**Authenticator**

```
class TokenAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun authenticate(route: Route, response: Response): Request? {

        // Refresh your token here


        //returned new request with updated header
        return response.request().newBuilder()
                .header(header_key, new_token)
                .build()
    }
}
```

authenticate() will trigger when your api call getting 401.

Comment: is your refresh token api getting success?